# How to compress an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say, I have an array with 1000 values (integers). And I need from this array to have an array with f.e. 400 values (the number can be changed, f.e. 150, etc.).

So I need to return each 2.5th array value, i.e. 1st, 3rd, 6th, 8th, 11th, etc.

Is this somehow possible?

I dont need a code, I just need some way, how to do it.

**EDITED:**

My array is array of elevations (from another array with GPS coordinates). And I want to draw a 2D model of elevation. Lets say, my map will always have `400px` width. `1px` = 1 point of elevation. Thats why I need each 2.5th elevation value...

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I dont need a code, I just need some way, how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps something like `$shrink = 400; $new = array_column(array_chunk($array, floor(count($array) / $shrink)), 0);`

Comment: @MarkBaker: I tried this, but it will return each second value, not 2.5th value.

Comment: `shuffle($array); array_splice($array, 400);` - Without any additional restrictions or rules, that's just about as good as anything else. You may even leave off the `shuffle`.

Comment: Well there isn't a 2.5th value, that's a physical impossibility.... perhaps you need to clarify with a real example what you expect to happen with the non integer results... do you expect the difference between the 2nd and the 3rd results?

Comment: @deceze: this cant be, I really need each 2.5th value

Comment: How exactly would that work? You're more or less discarding data at random then. Might as well make the entire thing random. What is it you're trying to do here?

Comment: Must the value match the value in the array entries? i.e. you could interpolate the intervening values and use an 'estimated' value. Just seen the update to the question.

Comment: With your clarification: how about using established visual scaling algorithms? You paint all the values as pixels into your graph, you'll just have to make them snap to a grid when painting a pixel. Depending on what you want the result to look like you either simply round, or you use sub-pixel rendering.

Comment: I did it... :-) Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is it:

```
$arr  = range(1, 1387); // f.e.
$cnt  = 296;            // f.e.

$new  = array();

$max  = count($arr);
$step = $max / $cnt;

for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i += $step) {
  $new[] = round($arr[(int)$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the 2.5th one. You effectively want to divide the set into blocks of five and get the first and third from each set.

```
 0   1   2   3   4
 5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14
```

You want the first and third columns.

This is PHP, so we've got 0-based arrays.

We can divide it into groups of 5 using the modulo operator `%`. We can then see if the return value is `0` (i.e. it's in the first column) or `2` (i.e. it's in the third column).

I'm going to presume your array has numeric keys starting from `0`.

```
// PHP 5.6
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($value, $key) {
    $mod = $key % 5;

    return ($mod === 0) || ($mod === 2);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

// pre-PHP 5.6
$filtered = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $mod = $key % 5;

  if (($mod === 0) || ($mod === 2)) {
    $filtered[$key] = $value;
  }
}

var_dump($filtered);
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted and thank you for your explanation about the groups.

Comment: Just problem is, if I dont need 400 elements in array, but 296 elements... and also if there is not 1000 elements in array, but more or less... :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about using the modulo `%` operator?

Say you want to make 1000 into 200 values, loop through all the items in the array and keep a counter, if the counter `%` 5 == 0 then put that value into a new array, or if != 0 then remove from array. We use modulo 5 because 1000 / 200 = 5.

Comment: I know, its simple, when its integer number, but when its float, then it is problem... lets say 1000 into 400... then `%` will not work

Comment: Alright, how about multiplying by 10 and after the modulo divide by 10? You cannot get more than 2 decimals but at least it's more accurate then rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the way to start with. It does not ensure that first and last elements are included in the output and, probably, has some other glitches. But since you requested the idea, here you go—[`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

$step = 2.5; 
$i = 0; 

$r = array_reduce($a, function($memo, $curr) use(&$i, $step) { 
  if($i === round($step * count($memo))) {
    $memo[] = $curr; 
  }
  $i++; 
  return $memo; 
}, []);

print_r($r);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 11
)
*/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try it... it doesnt matter, if there will be first or last element, I just need f.e. exactly 400 elements, and it should be each 2.5th, see my edit for more explanation.

Comment: This solution meets your needs as soon as you define `$step` properly (see result output.)

Comment: `[]` as second parameter of `array_reduce` is not working in `PHP 5.3`

Comment: Use `array()` instead.

Comment: I know, that `[]` means `array()`, but still its not working and it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty close to what you seem to be looking for. It will collect whichever values are closest (rounding down) to the float values.

```
$list = range(1,1000);
$targetSize = 300;
$new = array();

$step = count($list) / $targetSize;
$curStep = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++ ) {
  $curStep++;
  if( $curStep > $step ) {
    $new[] = $list[ floor($i) ];
    $curStep -= $step;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I wanted, except its not accurate, f.e. when `$targetSize = 400;`, array `$new` has only `399` elements.